# I can't wrap my head around "this" keyword in this code

Tags: javascript

I was going through promises in JS and came up with the weird output while logging "this".The sequence of logging "this" affected the output of the code.I thought I knew how "this" works but apparently I don't.Can anyone please help me to wrap my head around this code below:

```
const USER = {
    name: 'Glad Chinda',
    country: 'Nigeria',
    job: 'Fullstack Engineer'
  };

console.log(this);
Promise.resolve(USER).then(user => console.log(user.name));
console.log(this);

//OUTPUT
//{}
//{}
//Glad Chinda

------------------------------------------------------------------

//Removing the first console.log(this)
const USER = {
    name: 'Glad Chinda',
    country: 'Nigeria',
    job: 'Fullstack Engineer'
  };

Promise.resolve(USER).then(user => console.log(user.name));
console.log(this);

//OUTPUT
//{}
//Glad Chinda

------------------------------------------------------------------

//Removing the second console.log(this)
const USER = {
    name: 'Glad Chinda',
    country: 'Nigeria',
    job: 'Fullstack Engineer'
  };

console.log(this);
Promise.resolve(USER).then(user => console.log(user.name));

//OUTPUT
//{}
//Glad Chinda
------------------------------------------------------------------

//Removing both
const USER = {
    name: 'Glad Chinda',
    country: 'Nigeria',
    job: 'Fullstack Engineer'
  };

Promise.resolve(USER).then(user => console.log(user.name));

//OUTPUT
//Glad Chinda
```

Comment: In *all* of those cases, the `.then()` callback function is evaluated last; that's how Promises work. It has nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: Please review all those `console.log(this);` for scope - they all seem to be top level object as currently posted here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss So it means that irrespective of the order console.log(this) will be logged first despite the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" is the current scope you're working in.  Your issue seems to be your understanding of promises.  Promises execute asynchronously, which means the logging in the promise handler will happen last as it's execution is deferred as to not block the rest of the program execution.

Comment: Oho ok I think I got it now. Thank you so much. I am a beginner so I just couldn't understand what was going on.

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with scope. (Unless it's inside an arrow function, and even then scope is only used to determine which function's `this` to use.) It's to do with how the function is called. Since we're not told how the OP's function is called (or even whether it's inside a function at all), we can't actually answer the question about `this` (although it seems that they were just confused by the asynchrony, and `this` was irrelevant.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond this is a keyword referring to the object it belongs to, in javascript, this is more or less identical to scope. in this particular case, the code just appears to be an executed js file, so this is indeed the scope.

Comment: @bryan60, it doesn't mean "the object it belongs to", although I agree that in common cases this is a reasonable interpretation. More importantly, you are wrong to say that this object had anything at all to do with the function's scope. For one thing, scope is lexical and therefore fixed once the code is written (unless you're mucking about with `eval`), whereas the value of `this` can be, and often is, different each time a function is executed, because it depends crucially on the manner in which the function is called.

Comment: Not sure why you posted that link, I'm quite acquainted with how `this` works in JS. It has nothing to do with scope, and I didn't see anywhere in that w3schools link that said otherwise. (Although it wouldn't surprise me, w3schools is notorious for not always being accurate.) If we're trading links, I will offer [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md) as by far the best explanation I've ever seen (chapter 2 is most relevant in this context).

Comment: Because literally the first sentence is exactly what I wrote

Comment: Oh I see - well that's not the main thing I was criticising,  as I said it's true enough of the common use cases, at least if you don't ask yourself too much about what "belonging to an object" actually means. It's a typical oversimplification that a beginners' resource like w3schools might use. But the reason for my comment, and downvote, was the fallacious comment about scope, when the two concepts, which are both critical to JS, have almost nothing to do with each other.

Comment: You’re welcome to your opinion of how critical the difference is, but I find it inconsequential. In 10 years of JavaScript coding I’ve never encountered a situation where thinking in this manner was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Promises execute asynchronously, which means the execution after the line promise.resolve() happens parallely rather than sequentially.
You could try this to get a clear understanding:

```
Promise.resolve(USER).then(user => console.log(user.name));
Promise.resolve(USER).then(user => console.log(`${user.name} -> new entry`));
```

Run this code and see what it does.

Comment: Yaah I finally got it. It executes the rest of the codes parallely without disturbing the sequence and executes the promises sequentially.Thank you so much.